# Apply Windows native shadow to customized FireMonkey form BorderStyle?

Tags: windows, delphi, border, firemonkey, firemonkey-style

In FireMonkey, I created a custom BorderStyle for the application MainForm (using WindowBorderStyle for the non-client area).

Default forms without styling do have a Windows native shadow under their window, for example:

[image: Example form with shadow]

But this is not the case when a custom BorderStyle is assigned to a FireMonkey form.

Options I tried:

1. Adding a TShadowEffect to the style. Looks good in the StyleDesigner, but it doesn't actually work because it lies fully outside the MASK of the style.
2. Adding CS_DROPSHADOW to WindowClass.style. This gave a small shadow, but not the official Windows shadow.

I also tried to track down the way FireMonkey handles default forms and their shadows, but was not able to find this.

Anyone encountered this issue? How can I enable the native shadow?